# Logstash grok filter integer

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I need to index numerical data in my ElasticSearch DB and i'm using grok filter to parse the log line (which is all comma separated integers).

trying to use this format `%{NUMBER:userID_2:int}` did not work and no data was indexed and no exception appeared.

When i changed the type to "float" -i.e. `%{NUMBER:userID_2:float}` it worked just fine.

Any idea why i'm not able to index integers?

(Using elastic 1.4.4 and logstash 1.4.1)

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide log example and make sure all your logs is in integer format.

Comment: Log line:  20630,198595,214285,451,7907,206502,214285,3691,46011,112769,156888,184225,19708,26873,77739,35843,40659,263309,95184,105544,90,81,85,87,85,87,86,87,87,86,81,"2008-06-26 10:00:00"

Comment: Log line:  20630,198595,214285,451,7907,206502,214285,3691,46011,112769,156888,184225,19708,26873,77739,35843,40659,263309,95184,105544,90,81,85,87,85,87,86,87,87,86,81,"2008-06-26 10:00:00"

Comment: @BenLim anything?  :-(

Answer (score 0):

In "filter" section you set up match expression:

```
match => "%{NUMBER:user_id}"
```

and then you convert it:

```
mutate {
  convert => {
    "user_id" => "integer"
    ....
  }
}
```